# O que é essa tal classe __php_incomplete_class?

Tags: php

Eu sempre acabo descobrindo um monte de doidices nessa linguagem que eu tanto amo: O PHP!

O que seria essa misteriosa classe  `__PHP_Incomplete_Class`?

Eu "achei" ela acidentalmente, quando dei um `get_declared_classes`

Daí, na minha curiosidade, eu tentei instanciar a mesma.

```
$incomplete = new __PHP_Incomplete_Class;
```

Porém, quando eu tento acessar ou atribuir um valor a qualquer propriedade, um `Notice` é gerado:

```
$incomplete = new __PHP_Incomplete_Class;

$incomplete->test = 'teste';
```

> **Notice**: main(): The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition "unknown" of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded *before* unserialize() gets called or provide a __autoload() function to load the class definition in /var/www/lab/index.php on line 5

O que seria esse erro?

O que seria essa `__PHP_Incomplete_Class`?

E de onde surgiu esse `main` no **Notice** que foi gerado?

## Atualização:

Além de tudo que já foi dito anteriormente, há mais outra questão interessante sobre `__PHP_Incomplete_Class`: A função `is_object` retorna `FALSE` quando nós a checamos.

Veja:

```
var_dump(is_object(new __PHP_Incomplete_Class())); // (boolean) false
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Geralmente quando se tenta armazenar objetos na sessão, em arquivos ou transmiti-los através de sockets, o objeto pode ser referenciado como sendo da classe `__PHP_Incomplete_Class`, isso acontece porque a maneira correta de armazenar e recuperar um objeto na sessão (e também nos outros casos) é utilizar as funções `serialize()` e `unserialize()`.

Nota: é interessante notar que, em muitos casos (com a flag `session.auto_start` desabilitada no `php.ini`), é necessário incluir a definição da classe antes da chamada à função `session_start()`.

Comment: Muito esclarecedor! Mas ainda acho engraçado o jeito com o que o PHP lida com algumas coisas :)

Comment: Não muita padronização, nem sequer de nomes de métodos (snake_case e CamelCase)

Comment: Fora que tive de ir aos confins da terra pra encontrar esta informação

Answer (score 2):

Além do que já foi citado, é importante lembrar que o PHP retorna uma instância `__php_incomplete_class` quando você chama a função `unserialize` numa string que contenha uma serialização de uma classe que não existe no contexto atual.

Por exemplo:

- Crie a classe `X`
- Serialize a instância dela com `serialize(new X)`.
- Copie o resultado da mesma para `string`. é algo parecido com `O:1:"X":0:{}`.
- Delete a classe `X`.
- Chame `unserialize('O:1:"X":0:{}')`, sem a classe `X` estar declarada.

O PHP vai retornar o seguinte:

```
object(__PHP_Incomplete_Class)#198 (1) {
  ["__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name"]=>
  string(1) "X"
}
```

Já com a classe `class X {}` estando declarada no documento que usou `unserialize`, seria retornado isso:

```
object(X)#202 (0) {
}
```

**Cuidados**

Você deve tomar certos cuidados ao salvar certos tipos de dados em sessão. Por exemplo, imagine que você salvou as informações do usuário logado através de um objeto:

```
$_SESSION['usuario'] = Usuario::find(1); // retorna uma instância de Usuario
```

Se por algum motivo, por conta de uma manutenção, você alterou o nome da classe `Usuario` para `UsuarioSite`, por exemplo, o usuário que tiver a sessão salva, anterior a atualização da sua manutenção, vai ter problemas com o `__php_incomplete_class`, devido a não existência da referência (classe) `Usuario`.