# Erro ao utilizar um objeto na sessão

Tags: php

Galera está dando um erro estranho em meu código, existe o valor na sessão porem ele informa esta mensagem.

> [Wed Sep 02 13:55:17 2015] [error] [client 192.168.1.105] PHP Fatal error:  main() [function.main]: The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition "UsuarioID" of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded *before* unserialize() gets called or provide a __autoload() function to load the class definition  in /opt/lampp/htdocs/renan/suc_validacao.php on line 11, referer: http://127.0.0.1:58889/http-services/emulator-webserver/ripple/userapp/x/C/Users/hotsystems/AppData/Local/XDK/xdk-scratchdir/b9796bb6-a6c6-4479-94a3-7154a6043f83/platforms/android/assets/www/index.html

Minha classe

```
<?php

/* Declara o bloco de definições do usuário logado SUC */

if (!class_exists('UsuarioID')) {

class UsuarioID {

    public $COD_IDENT_USUAR = -9999;
    public $COD_IDENT_IGREJ = -9999;
    public $TXT_NOMEX_USUAR = 'Anônimo';

    function setCOD_IDENT_USUAR($p_COD_IDENT_USUAR) {
        $this->COD_IDENT_USUAR = $p_COD_IDENT_USUAR;
    }

    function getCOD_IDENT_USUAR() {
        return $this->COD_IDENT_USUAR;
    }

    function setCOD_IDENT_IGREJ($p_COD_IDENT_IGREJ) {
        $this->COD_IDENT_IGREJ = $p_COD_IDENT_IGREJ;
    }

    function getCOD_IDENT_IGREJ() {
        return $this->COD_IDENT_IGREJ;
    }

    function setTXT_NOMEX_USUAR($p_TXT_NOMEX_USUAR) {
        $this->TXT_NOMEX_USUAR = $p_TXT_NOMEX_USUAR;
    }

    function getTXT_NOMEX_USUAR() {
        return $this->TXT_NOMEX_USUAR;
    }

    function sair() {
        $this->COD_IDENT_USUAR = -9999;
        $this->COD_IDENT_IGREJ = -9999;
        $this->TXT_NOMEX_USUAR = "Anônimo";
    }

}

}
?>
```

> Já tentei implementar o método __sleep já tentei dar serialize(); porém em ambos os casos não funcionaram, o que mais pode ser ?

Comment: Provalvemente você deve ter colocado nessa sessão algum objeto. Acho que isso pode ser corrigido se o objeto implementar os métodos  mágicos `__wakeup` e `__sleep`

Comment: Poderia fazer uma resposta como exemplo ?

Comment: Veja as respostas dessa pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/75109/o-que-%C3%A9-essa-tal-classe-php-incomplete-class

Comment: Como ficaria isto em meu caso ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro acontece por não ter include o arquivo da classe no documento, a solução foi muito simples bastou adicionar:

```
global $suc;
include 'suc.php'
```

Na página onde eu utilizo a classe na sessão. Não foi necessário usar `serialize()` e `unserialize()` e muito menos o método `__sleep`. O erro foi resolvido ao adicionar um `include 'suc.php'` que é a minha classe.