# Serialização de Objetos (serialize/unserialize)

Tags: php

Estava vendo um tópico sobre [serialize](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.serialization.php) no PHP.

Uma função bem interessante, mas em vista, muito pouco usada.

---

Sobre a função, gostaria de saber:

- Um exemplo, de **onde iria aplicar essa função** em um cenário real?
- **Qual a vantagem** de utilizar o `serialize` em relação a uma variável qualquer?
- Por que fazer a **serialização de um objeto**?
- **Por que então usar dois passos a mais** (serialize/unserialize) para algo que pode ser "tratado" direto?

Comment: Isso é necessário mais raramente, se você quiser persistir o objeto (em arquivo, memória ou banco de dados) e recuperar mais tarde. Ou seja, em casos em que não dá para "passar direto".

Comment: @bfavaretto nem imaginava isso. Muito interessante. (apesar de como disse, em raras necessidades) 

Comment: Complementando e respondendo a última questão (_Por que então usar dois passos a mais?_). Existem objetos que utilizam recursos externos (`resources`). Que podem ser conexão com o banco de dados, stream, etc.. Esses recursos não podem ser persistidos e nem fechados/abertos automaticamente. O fato desses dois passos a mais, pode ser para fechar um recurso (durante `serialize`) e recriar o recurso (durante `unserialize`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Gostaria de saber, um exemplo, onde iria aplicar essa função em um cenário real?

**Jobs**

Eu uso bastante para criar Jobs, particularmente uma implementação do Laravel.
Funciona basicamente assim: Você serializa uma instância de uma classe que vai executar uma ação específica e salva ela no banco de dados. Aí você desserializa essa classe e chama um método específico dessa classe através da linha de comando.

**Sessão**

Além disso, o PHP nativamente usa o serialize para poder salvar os dados armazenados na variável `$_SESSION`, e `unserialize` quando você vai recuperar esses dados.

Veja o que o pequeno código abaixo faz:

```
session_save_path('tmp_sessions');
session_start();

$_SESSION['nome'] = 'Wallace';
```

Acima eu defini que as sessões serão salvas dentro da pasta `tmp_sessions`. Após executar o script, aparece um arquivo dentro da pasta `tmp_sessions/sess_st3e3ksr5vjsj8h5rrm57u11l4`, com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
nome|s:7:"Wallace";
```

> Qual a vantagem de utilizar o serialize em relação a uma variável qualquer?

Acho que parte dessa pergunta foi respondida acima, mas é natural usar serialize em casos onde você precisa recuperar esses dados mais tarde, de maneira que o PHP conseguia recuperá-lo com o mesmo estado que ele foi criado.

## Observações importantes

A serialização visa o armazenamento de dados em formatos que são interpretados pelo PHP para uma recuperação futura. Você deve ter em mente que há algumas restrições quanto a serialização de dados.

Uma delas é `Closure` e também Classes Anônimas. Obviamente esses dados não podem ser serializados nativamente por representarem uma estrutura temporária, o que dificultaria bastante a reconstrução desses objetos.

Nos casos onde você precisa implementar serialização em uma instância específica de um objeto, talvez seja necessário definir como o PHP vai se comportar quando mantar serializar este objeto, no caso, ou criando o método `__wakeup` e `__sleep` ou implementando a interface nativa `Serializable`, que tem os métodos `serialize` e `unserialize`. Esses métodos tem como objetivo "apontar" para o PHP o que será ou não serializado daquele objeto.

Vejamos o exemplo do JOB que citei anteriormente.

No caso abaixo, considere que estou querendo criar um "trabalhador" que vai enviar os e-mails para mim pela linha de comando, para eu não ter que fazer isso pelo http.

No HTTP:

```
interface Trabalho
{
    public function trabalhar();
}   


class EmailNotificacao implements Trabalho, Serializable
{

    public function __construct($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function trabalhar()
    {

        $usuario = Usuario::find($this->id);

        Email::texto('Enviando email para o usuário', $usuario->email);
    }


    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(['id' => $this->id]);
    }

    public function unserialize($data)
    {
        $properties = unserialize($data);

        $this->id = $properties['id'];
    }
}



$id = 1;

BancoDeDados::inserir('trabalhos', serialize(new EmailNotificacao($id)));
```

No caso acima, isso me permite inserir a instância de uma classe serializada no banco, porque a serialização sempre retorna uma `string`, o que pode ser facilmente incluído numa coluna do tipo `TEXT`.

Agora, um script que está no seu cronjob rodando e têm acesso as mesmas definições de classe da sua aplicação http poderá recuperar os dados através da desserialização.

Veja:

```
// no script do cronjob


$trabalho = BancoDeDados::obterPrimeiro('trabalhos');

$trabalho_instancia = unserialize($trabalho['dado_serializado']);


if ($trabalho_instancia instanceof Trabalho)
{

    $trabalho_instancia->trabalhar();
    BancoDeDados::deletar($trabalho_instancia->id);
}
```

Veja um pequeno exemplo da costumização do comportamento de `serializable` no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/ctskoK)

> Por que então usar dois passos a mais (serialize/unserialize) para algo que pode ser "tratado" direto?

É porque você está pensando na aplicação numa única execução. Nesses casos, realmente não tem sentido serializar os dados - a não ser que seja algo bem específico.

Como eu disse, o objetivo da serialização é criar uma string contendo uma representação de uma estrutura de dados do PHP.

Isso pode ser muito útil para você salvar um objeto em um local específico para recuperá-lo posteriormente, como é feito no caso da sessão.

Se não fosse a serialização, como você poderia salvar `arrays`, `strings` ou até mesmo instâncias de determinados objetos na sessão da sua aplicação?

Repare que no caso das sessões você além de obter o valor armazenado anteriormente, você obtém ele no mesmo tipo. Se você salvar um `int`, você sempre terá o mesmo `int` na nova chamada da página.

Para você entender melhor, a sessão funciona basicamente assim:

Crie o script `serialize.php` e em seguida crie um arquivo `session.txt` na mesma pasta, vazio.

Agora adicione isso ao seu script:

```
$file = 'session.txt';

// desserializa o conteúdo do arquivo

$_session = unserialize(file_get_contents($file));

// Se for false, é que o arquivo está vazio

if ($_session === false) {
    // então definimos que queremos que a variável seja um array
    $_session = [];
}

// mostra os dados da sessão

var_dump($_session);

$_session['nome'] = 'wallace';

if (! isset($_session['quantidade_execucao']))
{
    $_session['quantidade_execucao'] = 0;
}


// adiciona uma contagem para cada vez que o script é executado
$_session['quantidade_execucao']++;


// salvas os dados serializados no arquivo

file_put_contents($file, serialize($_session));
```

Basicamente, é assim que a sessão funciona, e não seria manter os estados das variáveis, como no exemplo acima, se não houvesse a serialização.

## Mas por que não usar JSON, que é tão popular?

O `JSON` tem como objetivo a comunicação entre linguagens ou aplicações diferentes. Já o `serialize` do PHP serve unica e exclusivamente para o PHP.

Além do mais, o `json_encode` do PHP, quando se trata de objetos, é uma via de mão única, pois o mesmo apenas é capaz de determinar como será que os dados de um objeto (em se tratando de uma classe específica) será serializado para JSON, porém **não existe a opção de se fazer o contrário**.

Ou seja, o `json_decode` nunca poderia reconstruir um objeto do tipo `ArrayObject`, por exemplo. Porém o serialize é capaz de lidar com isso perfeitamente.

**Observação: se você tentar desserializar um serial que contenha uma classe inexistente no esopo, o PHP retornará um erro, dizendo que não pode desserializar __php_incomplete_class.

Sempre é necessário, ao trabalhar com serialização de classes, que ela esteja incluída tanto onde se serializa quanto onde se desserializada.

serialize não faz a mágica de salvar o código fonte da sua classe nele, ele apenas armazena as informações necessárias para reconstruir uma instância. Para isso, é necessário que a classe exista!

Veja essa pergunta que fiz sobre o assunto:

- [O que é essa tal classe __php_incomplete_class?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/75109/o-que-%C3%A9-essa-tal-classe-php-incomplete-class)

Comment: Wallace, desculpa a ignorância, mas é um assunto bem "novo" e distinto esse negócio! rs... Eu "sinteticamente" entendi, mas "analiticamente", não tenho certeza! . Ele irá "guardar" meu objeto/instância em seu estado atual? Todas as propriedades do objeto, algo mais? Sempre é salvo em `$_SESSION`? Se encerrar a conexão, irei perder?

Comment: Complementando a ultima frase, recupera-lo sem perder os formatos dos valores salvos, incluindo objetos de classes. O que poderia ser uma grande vantagem (desde que a classe esteja já declarada previamente nas requisições seguintes).

Comment: @rbz calma aí, jovem. Eu vou criando a resposta as prestações mesmo, kkkkk

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Estou percebendo isso! rs Mas se eu for lembrando de algo sobre o contexto vou descrevendo, assim consigo te passar melhor onde estou com meu entendimento! rs ✌️

Comment: @rbz tá aí. Leia principalmente o último exemplo, fazendo testes com ele. Vai perceber como a sessão funciona.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Agora o negócio ficou sério! rs ... Agora eu que preciso de um tempo para digerir!  Mas vou ver, entender, testar... aguarde..rs